# How to display an image on crystal reports from mysql blob field?

Tags: mysql, vb6, crystal-reports-xi

Hi I am creating a crystal report using VB6. I am storing an image in a mysql blob field. I want to display the picture on my report. I have been googling for 1 week but I could not get the solution.

Answer (score 0):

For the graphic control in your report, you will have a property that can take a file path. Set that to the field that has the jpg file name.

1. Insert an Image on the report (don't drag the blob field - go to the Insert menu.)
2. Right-click on the image and select Format Graphic.  Select the Picture tab and click on the "x-1" button by Graphic Location.  Type in your formula here.  Click on Save and Close.

And also check there is no Issue with importing the BLOB info to the table. That should do it, I think.